# Python ImportError Keyword Argument

Tags: python

I have the following problem.
I want to have an object class, which takes as superclass a predefined object as keyword argument.

But I'm getting the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Object
```

Code:

```
import Object

class Object:

    defaultobject = Object('defaultobject', None)

    def __init__(self, name, superclass = defaultobject):
        self.__name = name
        self.__superclass = superclass
```

Comment: Are you trying to import a class in the same file where it's defined?

Comment: Yes, I tried this cause if I don't do this, the compiler says: Undefined variable: Object

Comment: What do you aim to achieve with that import statement?

Comment: To be able to create the Object and store it in defaultobject

Comment: `import` is used to import *modules*. But `Object` is not a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import the module you are *in*. You'll have to move the `Object()` instantiation to  *after* the class definition:

```
class Object:
    defaultobject = None

    def __init__(self, name, superclass=None):
        self.__name = name

        if superclass is None:
            superclass = self.defaultobject
            if superclass is None
                # No default set yet, use `self` instead (it'll *be* the default)
                superclass = self

        self.__superclass = superclass

Object.defaultobject = Object('defaultobject', None)
```

You can always add more attributes to a class definition, but to *create* an instance of a class you first need to have defined it.

The `superclass is None` dance is needed, because you otherwise have a catch-22 here; you cannot create an instance of `Object` without setting `Object.defaultobject` first. Which you cannot do, because you haven't created the default yet.

Comment: And how do I access defaultobject??

I'm getting the error: Undefined Variable: defaultobject

Comment: @user2221323: Ah, I missed that in the signature. Updated, use a sentinel default instead (`None` will do fine here).

Comment: still not working :/
superclass = self.defaultobject
AttributeError: Object instance has no attribute 'defaultobject'

Comment: @user2221323: Ah, what you are trying to do is actually impossible. Let me think up a way around that. You are going into too many self-references here.

Comment: If i want to print the superclass with     def __str__(self): return '%s(%s)' % (self.__name, self.__superclass) I'm getting "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" and running into recursion :/

Comment: @user2221323: Yes, that is because you are going to print the same object again and again. You have a recursive nesting here. *That cannot be avoided*. What do you expect the `__superclass` attribute of the `__superclass` attribute to be? You could set a sentinel value there; `Object.defaultobject = Object('defaultobject', None, object())` perhaps.

Comment: Ah ok, I got it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be solved by removing the import library from parent class which is also imported by some of its child classes. if your child class is also using import object then removing that from parent will solve the issue.